# The Beautiful Queen

Tags: riddle

Can you solve this riddle?

> Among the flowers in the old square a beautiful queen sleeps.
>
> Her dress is covered with moss and the light is off, it’s vampire time.

<sub>[(source)](http://www.briddles.com/riddles/who-am-i/?source=stack&external=1)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you a

> Street light?

Among the flowers in the old square a beautiful queen sleeps.

> There are street lights in town squares.

Her dress is covered with moss and the light is off, it’s vampire time.

> It is a vampires time to go away during the day or in any light so that is when the light is off, when the vampire can be around it.

I did not use my computer other than to answer this.